# Chai post request of type form

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, multipartform-data, chai

I am trying to post a form chai which need to include file.

```
chai.request(app).keepOpen()
  .post('/api/v1/myRoute')
  .type('form')
  .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${ token }`)
  .send({
    note: 'dataset description note',
    sl: 'en',
    tl: 'pt',
    file: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/testFiles/myFile.tsv')
  });
```

But I get no file on the other side.
I am pretty sure that here is some syntax failure but I can't find similar examples to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, I hope this will help someone :)

```
chai.request(app).keepOpen()
  .post('/api/v1/myRoute')
  .type('form')
  .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${ token }`)
  .field('note', 'dataset description note')
  .field('sl', 'en')
  .field('tl', 'pt')
  .attach('file', fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/testFiles/myFile.tsv'))
```